# How multiple authentication scheme work internally in .NET 6 world?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, .net-6.0

It took me some time to get multiple authentication methods to work in my .NET 6 world, but I want to understand bit more how this thing works internally.

This is my code:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {   // setup Authority etc 
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                 {
                     OnAuthenticationFailed = ctx =>
                     {
                         // So I can either log or just put a breakpoint
                     },
          
                     OnChallenge = ctx =>
                     {
                         // So I can either log or just put a breakpoint
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     },

                     OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
                     {
                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                     },

                     OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                     {
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     }
                 };
             }).AddJwtBearer("PrepIdentityServer", options =>
             {
                 // ###setup###
                 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                 {
                     OnAuthenticationFailed = ctx =>
                     {
                         // So I can either log or just put a breakpoint
                     },
                     
                     OnChallenge = ctx =>
                     {
                         // So I can either log or just put a breakpoint
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     },

                     OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
                     {
                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                     },

                     OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                     {
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     }
                 };
             });
```

Then in my controller, if I enable both schemes:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,PrepIdentityServer")]
public class PortfolioSeriesController
```

What I see is:

1. Get token from first authority (e.g. Azure AD) and send request
2. Both AuthenticationSchemes will be invoked. As the token is from first authority, first one succeed, and the second fail.
3. The response is 200 as expected.

However, will this trigger a performance issue as my Web API is under heavy load?

Looking at the behaviour, internally both authentication schemes will be called as async tasks. My guess is that the authentication only finish when both tasks are finished, but what if one authentication takes a long time to finish?

Or the method is very lightweight or cached, so I shouldn't really worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple JwtBearer handlers as you have done it makes no sense for me. Because JwtBearer is all about protecting APIs and converting incoming access tokens to a user instance.

JwtBearer does not handle when the user is challenged. If you use AddOpenIDConnect, then it would make more sense, because then the user could be redirected to different authentication services depending on what the user is trying to access.

Summary, JwtBearer does not handle user logins, only AddOpenIDConnect does that.